# Outlook add-in not visible in outlook Calendar

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have created a custom add-in and I am able to add/get it in the outlook mail but it is not visible in my outlook calendar. Also, I am trying to add it by clicking on the calendar event->more options->get add-ins but seems like the button is not clickable as nothing is fetched.

Comment: What did you specify in the manifest file?

Comment: Do you expect to see a ribbon UI for a calendar item?

Comment: Can you please specify the platform you're facing the issue or does it happen in all the platforms? 
Moreover, make sure you have the manifest rules as the answer below suggests.

Comment: <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  Above is my manifest file code. The issue is for both the outlook app and the browser.

Comment: It would be great if you post the whole manifest file, so we could analyze it in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you specified correct rules in the manifest file:

```xml
 <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
```

Plus in the manifest file for the ribbon UI you need to specify different extension points for messages and appointments. The manifest contemplates these:

```xml
<!-- Message compose form -->
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
<!-- Appointment compose form -->
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
<!-- Message read form -->
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
<!-- Appointment read form -->
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
```

You can find the full sample add-in source code at
https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo .

Comment: My issue is that I am able to add my custom add-in in the outlook mail and the ribbon is visible in the mail only but I am not able to add my custom add-in in the outlook calendar not I am able to see my ribbon in the calendar. This issue is for both the outlook app and the browser.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a sample add-in mentioned in my post? Does it work correctly?

Comment: My issue got solved by adding the required ExtensionPoints for the outlook calendar but it is still not visible for the outlook to-do

Comment: the extension points was exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot strange helper

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not support add-ins in Outlook To Do. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.